# I can't create a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I can't create a simple skeleton file for tests named 'tests/test_NAME.rb' what can I do? The directions told me to create a file called tests/test_NAME.rb. I did that and when I saved the file, my computer said that the file is not valid. I put in the following in the tests/test_NAME.rb file.

```
    require "./lib/NAME.rb"
    require "test/unit"

    class TestNAME < Test::Unit::TestCase

      def test_sample
        assert_equal(4, 2+2)
      end

    end
```

Any advice is good thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the directory called "test" in your application directory.

Then add a new file in that test directory by the shortcut "Command + N" and save it as "test_NAME.rb".

After that write your test code and run.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try to create the tests directory first? And then cd that directory and create a new file named Test_NAME.rb After the file is created, you can edit it.